# CSS - before pseudo element behind element text

Tags: css, positioning, pseudo-element

I try to learn how to use pseudo elements in CSS and I am facing a problem. I try to create a container that contains some text and a pseudo element.

But I wan't the pseudo element to be behind the elements text but before the background color. I don't know how to achieve this.
I want the pseudo element to be part of and before the background color. But to be behind the containers actual content.

Here is a short snippet of the exact problem I am facing:

```css
.container {
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it acceptable if `::before` element goes behind blue `.container` and not just text?

Comment: @Omkar76 No that is not acceptable. I want the pseudo element to be part of and before the background color. But to be behind the containers actual content.

Comment: all you need is position:relative to h1. No need z-index

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, but I want to be able to reuse this class in different pages. I want it to be independent of what child elements it may or may not have.

Comment: but you accepted an answer adding styles to child elements. I gave you a simplified solution

Comment: if you want it to be independant add `z-index:-1` to pseudo element and `position:relative;z-index:0` to container

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes because it think it is a clean solution to the problem. It doesn't need to be applied to the children and it works even tough the div doesn't have any.

Comment: I am suggesting that you simply need to add `position:relative`. No need z-index.

Comment: @TemaniAfif To your second question: Wouldn't  giving the z-index -1 of the pseudo make it go behind the entire container?

Comment: *make it go behind the entire container?* --> you need to also set z-index to container (see my previous comment)

Comment: When the z-index of the entire container is bigger then the z-index of the pseudo element. Then the container and its background would be in front of the pseudo element.

Comment: I want the background of the container element behind the pseudo element and I want the pseudo element behind the content of the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `z-index` to childs of container.

```css
.container {
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.container>* {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to achieve this without using extra dom elements?

Comment: @Stephen edited. check the update